# TFS Build Service failing

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, virtual-machine, tfsbuild

Brief Intro:
I have a web application on Microsoft Azure.  This webapp uses azure's deployment functionality to provide continuous integration and deployment.  I was able to utilize Visual Studio Online right up until my build minutes maxed out at 60 minutes. Due to this limit I turned to setting up a build server of my own.

Situation:
I have set up a Windows Server 2012 Datacenter Virtual Machine on Azure with Team Foundation Server installed on it.  I set up TFS to be a Build Service. After I got that set up and connected to my VSO account, I modified the build configuration to use the newly created build server (instead of the Hosted Build Controller).  The build ran fine up until the deployment portion (previously working with the HBC) where it failed with the following message:

```
    Exception Message: TF401071: Could not find the element within the process parameter. Details:
Property 'DoNotDelete' does not exist on JObject. (type BuildParameterNotFoundException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter.GetValueT
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteInResolutionContextT
   at System.Activities.InArgument`1.TryPopulateValue(LocationEnvironment targetEnvironment, ActivityInstance activityInstance, ActivityExecutor executor)
   at System.Activities.ActivityInstance.InternalTryPopulateArgumentValueOrScheduleExpression(RuntimeArgument argument, Int32 nextArgumentIndex, ActivityExecutor executor, IDictionary`2 argumentValueOverrides, Location resultLocation, Boolean isDynamicUpdate)
   at System.Activities.ActivityInstance.ResolveArguments(ActivityExecutor executor, IDictionary`2 argumentValueOverrides, Location resultLocation, Int32 startIndex)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: Property 'DoNotDelete' does not exist on JObject. (type JsonException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JPath.Evaluate(JToken root, Boolean errorWhenNoMatch)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter.GetValue
```

I'm using the GitContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml deployment settings (defined by azure)

The only reason I'm here is I couldn't find anything on google for that error.  It could be that I'm tired and missing something, but my hopes are that someone will be able to assist me in troubleshooting this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build ended up working this morning.  Not sure why that error occurred.  Thanks anyway.